# Regex: How to match text between dynamic text starting with fixed symbols using Java

Tags: java, regex

How to get value1 and value2 from this string with regex?
These ('>>' and '>>') characters should always be searched because they are fixed in the large string, and the text after them is always dynamic.

```
...
>>(dynamic text)
value1
value2
<<(dynamic text)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work

`>>.*?\n((?:.|\n)*?)<<`

You can view it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/xazxuc/2).

**Explanation**

- `>>`

  - Match `>>` literally
- `.*?\n`

  - Match everything up to and including the newline
- `((?:.|\n)*?)`

  - Capture any character or new line lazily
- `<<`

  - Match `<<` literally

Comment: See my edit. I want to include in regex '<<' and '>>' because these are the mandatory elements on which to find where to search. The text after these elements '<<' '>>' of the same row is always dynamic, not fixed

Comment: See my updated answer